# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined [Galleria-1.4.2.js]

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, galleria

I'm getting the following error in my console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined    galleria-1.4.2.min.js:2
```

trying to use Galleria.io, version 1.4.2 with the basic "classic theme". I do have jQuery (v1.10.2) included and the following code which should be the basic code for getting the galleria image gallery to work:

```
<script src="galleria/galleria-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('.galleria', {responsive: true, height: 0.724, lightbox: true});
</script>
```

and guess what, it seems to work perfectly. BUT, I'm having this error in my console and I'm not allowed to have errors in my console. Neither do I like error messages in my console...

I have no clue what is causing this and what I can do about it, all I know it's triggered by the following line:

```
Galleria.run('.galleria', {responsive: true, height: 0.724, lightbox: true});
```

Even if I would leave the options blank. I'm also using bootstrap v3 if that might have anything to do with it.

The selector is a class and not an ID, but I've seen it in example code so it souldn't be a problem. I have multiple small image galleries on one page, so 0, 1 or more so working with ID's is not a good option. My application does require this.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow Galleria User. Your problem is

```
Galleria.loadTheme('/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
```

You have to ensure its loaded before

```
Galleria.run('.galleria', {responsive: true, height: 0.724, lightbox: true});
```

is called.

To do so, I loaded the Theme in the Header after the Galleria.js.
I invoke the Galleria.run Command in a script-tag after the Galleria Container containing the Pictures.